# Calculating distance for a system consisting of a hanging a cylinder with a rope of fixed length and fixed anchor points?

Tags: geometry

So this picture represents what I am trying to do: [image]

I know the total length of the rope drawn in red. Lets call it $T$. I also know $x$, which is the distance between the two anchor points and the radius of the cyliner that is being suspended. I am completely stuck trying to find symbolically the segment labled $L$ in the diagram and the distance of the center of the cylinder from the center between the two anchor points. I have filled a few pages trying to jot things down but haven't come up with the right machenery to describe this situation and find the desired values. Any help would be appreciated.

UPDATE:
I am trying to use Newton's Method to solve the equaiton in the answer provided below. This was my process:

First I realized that with newtons method I am looking for the zeros of a function. So I re-wrote the equation as a function where the value of L at the zeros would give me the answer that I desire:

$f(L) = 2L + r\pi + 2arccos\Big( \frac{rx + \sqrt{L^{4}+L^{2}r^{2}-L^{2}x^{2}}}{L^2 + r^2} \Big)$ - k

*k is the total length of the red rope in the picture. The next step that I took as I tried to complete Newtons method was to take the derivative. This is what I computed:

$ f'(L) = 2 + 0 - \Bigg( \frac{2r\Big(  \frac{4L^3 + 2Lr^{2} - 2Lx^{2}}{2(L^2 + r^2) \sqrt{L^{4}+L^{2}r^{2}-L^{2}x^{2}}} - \frac{2L{ \sqrt{L^{4}+L^{2}r^{2}-L^{2}x^{2}}}+rx}{(L^2 + r^2)^2} \Big)} {\sqrt{1- \frac{(\sqrt{L^{4}+L^{2}r^{2}-L^{2}x^{2}}+rx)^2}{(L^2 + r^2)^2}}}  \Bigg) - 0$

Now moving on from here I should plug in constants for k, r, and x and start going through the calculations for Newtons method and for my first guess use $L_{o}$ as $\frac{k-\pi r}{2}$

Is that the correct way forward?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Better to introduce an angle an some ausiliary lines. In the above configuration, the length of the red rope is given by $2L+(\pi+2\theta)r$. On the other hand, $\frac{r}{\tan\theta}$ is the distance of the "virtual apex" from a tangency point, and the ratio between $L$ and such a distance, by triangle similarities, equals $\frac{r\cos\theta-x}{r\cos\theta}$, so:

$$ L\sin\theta = r\cos\theta-x $$
and
$$ \theta = \arccos\left(\frac{r x+\sqrt{L^4+L^2 r^2-L^2 x^2}}{L^2+r^2}\right).\tag{1} $$
There are no simple ways for solving (with respect to $L$) the trascendental equation

$$ k = 2L+r\left[\pi + 2\arccos\left(\frac{r x+\sqrt{L^4+L^2 r^2-L^2 x^2}}{L^2+r^2}\right) \right] \tag{2}$$
that is similar to [Kepler's equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kepler%27s_equation), but numerical methods based on variations of [Newton's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method) work pretty nicely. A reasonable starting point for Newton's iteration is $L\approx\frac{k-\pi r}{2}$.

Comment: I am still looking over the answer but as a side note what program was used to produce the figure that you used?

Comment: @sTr8_Struggin: just Geogebra, https://www.geogebra.org/

Comment: D' Aurizo One question about how you got to k. I think that it is a constant to solve the transcendental equation. But did you plug in $\theta$ and use a trig identity to get the right side into shape?

Comment: @sTr8_Struggin: I get that the total length of the rope ($k$) is easy to describe in terms of $r,L,x$ and $\theta$. But $\theta$ is a function of $r,x,L$, hence $k$ is a function of $r,x,L$.

Comment: D' Aurizio Please see my update on the question. Is that essentially what you are suggesting? I re-visited this problem and I tried to come up with a solution.

Comment: @sTr8_Struggin: yes, it is exactly what I was suggesting.